# XML as Database in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, plist

We have to write a directory application in Objective-C , we now use plist xml file to read data and write data , and store some data in it .

The plist xml file generated from mysql database , to avoid scaling problems , we have to decide weather to stay with xml plist files or move every thing to SQLLite ?  as we estimated the maximum file size of xml is 10MB .

Any Suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to move to CoreData, which I'd prefer over SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a sqllite dbs, with the right wrappers it's very easy to get data and write data without parsing everything and sqllite is very fast...

Answer (score 0):

Heres the issue with switching to SQLite, the file size of the database will be at least 3x the size of the plist. SQLite databases store a significant amount of information besides what the app generates from the user interaction.

As for using a plist over 10MB's, if the user is consistently writing to that file, there will be some noticeable delay unless you place the writing on a new thread.

You can always try [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) as well. Even with this option, you will need to restructure and move your data. This will also require a ton of new code to your application.

Answer (score 0):

You should also look into `NSCoding` and `NSKeyedArchiver`, which is almost exactly the same as an XML Plist, only it's a binary format (so much more compact) and it's faster, and it supports pointers (so if the same object is in multiple places when you write the file, it will still be the same object when you read it).

Generating an `NSCoding` file from a MySQL database could be a challenge (I've never tried), but you could always generate a plist, and then immediately convert it to the binary format once it's on the device.

My rule of thumb is if it fits in RAM you should use `NSCoding`, if it doesn't fit in RAM you should use SQLite or Core Data.

I would always avoid XML on an iOS device, disk space is at a high premium. Obviously sometimes you need XML though, especially if you're going to allow the user to import/export files in and out of your app and they expect something XML based.